# JSoup проблема с запятой

Tags: java, get, jsoup

Необходимо сгенерировать url типа /address?id=1&param=VAL1,VAL2
Пытаюсь отправить param:

```
 Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .data("id", "1")
                .data("param", val1 + "," + val2)
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .ignoreContentType(true)
                .execute();
```

Запятую переводит в %2C и в результате страница не найдена.

Как правильно отправлять такой параметр?

Comment: по-моему, только вписать непосредственно в `url`. Jsoup без вариантов пропускает аргументы `data()` через `UrlEncoder` и заменяет запятую.

Comment: @zRrr, и правильно делает. Пусть сервер с роутингом правит.